# What is the difference between "origin/main" and "origin/HEAD" in a git log?

Tags: git

When I do a `git log` I might see something like

```
commit 919fef06cb740f1695448a18cc0627ee173c3eca (HEAD -> main, origin/main, origin/HEAD)
Author: Me <me@me.org>
Date:   Wed May 19 11:52:32 2021 +0200

    Some comment
```

I understand, `HEAD` points to the current local branch, and I can see the state is the same as the main branch on the remote repository (`origin/main`). But what does `origin/HEAD` mean? Can I be on `origin/HEAD` without being on other remote branch? Is the following situation possible?

```
commit 919fef06cb740f1695448a18cc0627ee173c3eca (HEAD -> main, origin/HEAD)
Author: Me <me@me.org>
Date:   Wed May 19 11:52:32 2021 +0200

    Some comment
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`origin/HEAD` is the default remote branch, which means if you clone that repository then that branch will be checkedout by default.

Lets say that there are 2 branches on the remote repository `prod` and `main`, the branch `main` is set as the default branch in the remote repo so clone it the branch we will by default be working on will be `main`, if you change the default branch to `prod` on the remote repo and clone it again then we will be working on the branch `prod` by default.

Comment: Please do not forget to mark my answer as accepted if it solved your problem.

Comment: Of course. Thanks!